# Replace standard Login and Register form for Woocommerce

Tags: wp-login-form

When non-logged users click on "my-account" they see standard woocommerce login and register forms. I have a [short_code] of new login form. Is there any way to replace or redirect standard login and register forms which are a part of [woocommerce_my_account] with my [short_code]  My new form is also combines both register and login. So, I need replace both login and register  forms and use a new one instead. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override pretty much every WooCommerce template by copying them into a folder named "woocommerce" in your theme.

This is documented at [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

The login and register forms non-logged in users see when they click "my account" are genetared by the template file [`/myaccount/form-login.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/myaccount/form-login.php)

So what you need to do is copy this file from the directory to your theme's directory (so it is `/yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`) and from there edit it as desired